# Run C++ in command prompt - Windows

Tags: c++, windows, command-line

I know that everyone uses an IDE nowadays, but I just find it simpler to write my code in notepad++, compile it using a command prompt command, and run it from there too. At least that works for Java and Python. I've tried to get my head around how to do that with C++, and haven't been able to find anything good. Is there any compiler (like Java's JDK) that I can stick into my path and use the C++ equivalent of `javac` and `java` to run and compile my code from CMD?

Note: please don't post answers and comments about how IDEs are better - I know they are. I'm just used to doing it the old way :D

Comment: Sure, what operating system are you using?

Comment: Probably windows ... install the free version of visual studio and you can use the "cl" command.

Comment: @BLuefire: also, what C++ compilers do you have installed on your system?

Comment: You have to set the environment variable to run a c++ file anywhere. follow this video instructions on Youtube [How To Compile C & C++ Files On Windows 10 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40MWdFAGTzg)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It depends on what compiler you're using.

For example, if you are using Visual C++ .NET 2010 Express, run Visual C++ 2010 Express Command Prompt from the start menu, and you can simply compile and run the code.

```
> cl /EHsc mycode.cpp
> mycode.exe
```

or from the regular command line, you can run `vcvars32.bat` first to set up the environment. Alternatively search for `setvcvars.cmd` (part of a FLOSS project) and use that to even locate the installed VS and have it call `vcvars32.bat` for you.

Please check your compiler's manual for command lines.

Comment: Trying the same but I see "can't find crtdbg.h".

Answer (score 69):

**Steps to perform the task:**

1. First, [download](https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=2435&package_id=240780) and install the compiler.
2. Then, type the C/C++ program and save it.
3. Then, open the command line and change directory to the particular one where the source file is stored, using `cd` like so:

   ```
   cd C:\Documents and Settings\...
   ```
4. Then, to compile, type in the command prompt:

   ```
   gcc sourcefile_name.c -o outputfile.exe
   ```
5. Finally, to run the code, type:

   ```
   outputfile.exe
   ```

Comment: If you mention `cd`, you should mention that he should probably put gcc on the path first.

Comment: @MooingDuck MinGW installer do it for you

Comment: @Gigi: I normally use mingw-w64 which doesn't touch the path, alright then.

Comment: @MooingDuck @Gigi I'm using mingw-w64-install.exe on Windows. In CMD, I get `'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. What do I do?

Comment: Add the directory containing `g++` to the windows path. https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/fot-addpath.html

Comment: you probably will need to restart your PC to use new PATH, you can just refer your compiler manually, mine was installed like so: "C:\MinGW\bin\gcc"

Comment: Just want to mention (since it took me some time to figure it out): I think these commands are for running c files. If you are running C++ files, you should change the second command to g++ sourcefile_name.cpp -o outputfile.exe

Answer (score 46):

If you're running Windows then make use of this:

```
g++ -o program program.cpp
```

`g++` is the name of the compiler and `-o` is the option needed for creating a `.o` file. Program (without `.cpp` suffix) is the `exe` file and `program.cpp` is your source file that you want to compile.

```
g++ -o program program.cpp&program.exe
```

Use this shortcut to run the `.exe` file of the program. This might run in Linux but you may have to use `.out` suffix instead of `.exe`. Use this handy batch script to execute your programs on Windows:

```
@echo off&&cls
set /p pathName=Enter The Path where the file is located:%=%
cd %pathName%
REM set /p exec=Enter The Name of the executable you want to make:%=%
set /p file=Enter The Name of the file you want to compile:%=%
g++ -o %file% %file%.cpp
%file%.exe
```

save it as `cppExecutor.bat`

Also you could use the following commands on Unix (Linux and Mac) OS:

```
CC program.cc
```

If you want to use `gcc`:

```
gcc -o program program.cpp
```

With the shortcut:

```
gcc -o program program.cpp&program.exe
```

Comment: What would be the first `program` after `-o`?

Comment: @Memmo sorry for the late reply, the first `program` after `-o` will be the name of your code file (or whatever else you want to name your program (the `.exe` etc.)

Answer (score 12):

Sure, it's how most compilers got started. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is probably the most popular (comes with most flavors of *nix). Syntax is just `gcc my_source_code.cpp`, or `gcc -o my_executable.exe my_source_code.cpp`. It gets more complicated, of course, when you have multiple source files (as in implementation; anything `#include`d works automatically as long as GCC can find it).

[MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) appears to be a version of GCC for Windows, if that's what you're using. I haven't tried it though.

Pretty sure most IDEs also include a command line interface. I know Visual Studio does, though I have never used it.

Comment: Agree, I use it once in a while. In my case (Windows 10 64 bit) it was installed under: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Visual Studio 2017\Visual Studio Tools`. You can also get to it via the start menu (from there navigate to the "Visual Studio" folder/section). It will appear as: `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017` (in the case of VS 2017).

Answer (score 10):

I really don't see what your problem is, the question is rather unspecific. Given Notepad++ I assume you use Windows.

You have so many options here, from the MinGW (using the GCC tool chain and GNU `make`) to using a modern MSVC. You can use the [WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk) (`ddkbuild.bat/.cmd` or plain `build.exe`), the [Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/) (`nmake.exe`), other tools such as [premake](https://premake.github.io/) and [CMake](https://cmake.org/), or `msbuild` that comes with MSVC and the Windows SDK.

I mean the compiler names will differ, `cl.exe` for MSVC and the WDK and Windows SDK, `gcc.exe` for MinGW, but even from the console it is customary to organize your project in some way. This is what `make` and friends were invented for after all.

So to know the command line switches of your particular compiler consult the manual of that very compiler. To find ways to automate your build (i.e. the ability to run a simple command instead of a complex command line), you could sift through the [list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Build_automation) or pick one of the tools I mentioned above and go with that.

Side-note: it isn't necessary to ask people not to mention IDEs. Most professional developers have automated their builds to run from a command line and not from within the IDE (as during the development cycle for example), because there are so many advantages to that approach.

Comment: Does the Windows SDK come preinstalled with the platform?

Comment: @Bluefire: no, but the current versions of it can be downloaded for free and still contain a compiler (though not an optimizing one, unless you have a qualifying product such as MSVC Pro or higher). However, MS announced that they want to drop the compiler from WDK and SDK starting with Windows 8.

Answer (score 8):

1. Download MinGW form : https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/
2. use notepad++ to write the C++ source code.
3. using command line change the directory/folder where the source code is saved(using notepad++)
4. compile: g++ file_name.cpp -o file_name.exe
5. run the executable: file_name.exe

Comment: After installation `'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich you should add g++ to the PATH variable.

Comment: I just tried it and it worked; I installed cygwin64. A bit weird that one has to download from the internet (I'd like a single .exe file actually), but after I did so, I just did a "g++ hello_world.cpp -o hello_world.exe" and after doing a "hello_world" it just worked. \o/ Now I can use ruby to autogenerate tons of C++ code actually. :D

Answer (score 7):

- first Command is :

> `g++ -o program file_name.cpp`

- Second command is :

> `.\program.exe`

> *[Let us Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TH8qL.png)*

Answer (score 3):

A better alternative to MinGW is bash for powershell. You can install bash for Windows 10 using the steps given [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/)

After you've installed bash, all you've got to do is run the bash command on your terminal.

```
PS F:\cpp> bash
user@HP:/mnt/f/cpp$ g++ program.cpp -o program
user@HP:/mnt/f/cpp$ ./program
```

Comment: For me it shows - '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. why?

Answer (score 1):

Open cmd and go In Directory where file is saved. Then, 
For compile, 
g++ FileName. cpp
Or
gcc FileName. cpp

For Run, 
FileName. exe

This Is For Compile & Run Program.

Make sure, gcc compiler installed in PC or Laptop. 
And also path variable must be set.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used on MAC.

> Use your preferred compiler.

Compile with gcc.

```
gcc -lstdc++ filename.cpp -o outputName
```

Or Compile with clang.

```
clang++ filename.cpp -o outputName
```

After done compiling. You can run it with.

```
./outputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

have MinGW compiler bin directory added to path.

use `mingw32-g++ -s -c source_file_name.cpp -o output_file_name.o` to compile

then `mingw32-g++ -o executable_file_name.exe output_file_name.o` to build exe

finally, you run with `executable_file_name.exe`

Answer (score 0):

[Working 100%] from a Windows user.
Open the terminal(powershell) where your `file.cpp` is created.

1. `g++ file.cpp`  //it will compile the file into a.exe
2. `.\a.exe` //this will run the program.

Comment: `g++ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

`gcc <YourFileName>.cpp -o output.exe`

Now you can run `output.exe`

Answer (score -2):

**There are few ways:**

Using GNU Compiler Collection (GCC):

```
gcc -lstdc++ filename.cpp -o outputName
```

Using g++ command:

```
g++ -o outputName filename.cpp
```

Using clang++:

```
clang++ filename.cpp -o outputName
```

Answer (score -3):

You can run your code by just typing

To Compile
g++ file_name.cpp

To Run:
a

only this you have to do to run c++ code in cmd which is written in notepad++

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE7J9.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGD5r.png)

Comment: Almost every answer tells to use gcc. This answer does not contribute anything different. Recommend deleting. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/33526389)