# problems when running program in cmd

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I make a program in C++ using Notepad++, and then I'm trying to compile it in `cmd` using `g++ -o gt struct1.cpp`

But, there's this sentence shown in `cmd`:

> 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What must I do so I can compile and run the program?

Comment: You probably, probably, need this: http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started But this is way too broad a question to ask here.

Comment: "_I'm running it_" From the command that you wrote - you are not running it, you are trying to compile it. "_g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file._" Do you have g++ installed?

Comment: You need to install and set up a compiler. You can either install Visual Studio, mingw add the path to your system path or use Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10 for your first steps. There you have to do the same but I think it's easier with package manager: https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652211/g-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

If you're running windows then make use of this:

```
g++ -o program program.cpp
```

You can check this question
[Run C++ in command prompt - Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365850/run-c-in-command-prompt-windows)

> windows 10 "'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command

You can check this

['g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652211/g-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or)

Comment: I already use that but still it not work

Comment: @k.k have you set `g++` to your system path ?

Comment: i don't know it's my first time running in this laptop

Comment: You need to install `g++` to your laptop

Comment: aaah... so like that....

Comment: ok thanks u want to help me ^^

Comment: I already to try it but it won't changes... sorry...